# HttpErrorResponse in Angular 5 HttpClient get Request

Tags: angular, http, header, http-headers, angular4-httpclient

I need to fetch data from an endpoint that require authentication (login). Once logged in json object is shows up. I am using HttpClient module of angular to get data like this.

```
 return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
```

If I do this on other apis (that doesn't require (login) works fine. But If I change serviceUrl to endpoint that require login. It gives me error **Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error**

May be I can do like this?

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl, {headers: headers});
```

Comment: `If I change serviceUrl to endpoint that require login. It gives me error`, I guess you need to provide some credentials to api then, token maybe? Hard to say anything else when we don't know more :)

Comment: If it requires login, then how will your end point know if the user is logged in? You need to provide an authentication header

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta Can you tell, how to provide authentication header in my code?

Comment: well that depends on what your back end expects. It's done the same way, for example new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'some token here'}); Then your back end will use that to determine if the user is authenticated or not. But it's more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you need to pass in authorization headers.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization', btoa(<your login information here>)});
return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl, {headers: headers});
```

Comment: Can you explain about btoa, how to import it, syntax of login information inside it?

Comment: btoa is a function that comes with js, the syntax of login is a strong with <username>:<password>